# Is there a method for comparing point estimates after determining an interaction effect?

Tags: interaction, point-estimation

Suppose I'm conducting a multiple regression with two predictor variables (X1 and X2) and have found a significant interaction effect.

Let's say X1 = aggression, X2 = gender (men/women), and Y = health. So I want to know how aggression predicts health differently for men and for women. Because the interaction (X1*X2) is significant in the regression model, I run simple slopes and plot the slopes for men and women at 1 standard deviation below and 1 standard deviation above the mean of aggression: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIXno.jpg

Great, so I know the slopes are significantly different from one another.

But what I want to know is: how do I determine if point "Ym1" is signficantly different than point "Yw1"? Also how do I determine if point "Ym2" is significantly different than point "Yw2"?

Does anyone know what the standard method of doing this is? And what the method is called?
Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Have you looked at [Post-hoc tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_hoc_analysis#Tests)? I think this is what you are looking for. Have a look [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13659/are-t-tests-of-coefficients-in-multiple-regression-post-hoc-tests) too.

Comment: May be you should recraft your hypothesis and objective of your study. This will help users to respond correctly.